# Initialize ArrayList based on @RequestBody spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkInventory", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> checkInventory (
    // HEADERS
    @RequestBody CheckInventoryRequest checkInventoryRequest) throws Exception {

    // HEADERS LOGIC

    CheckInventoryResponse checkInventoryResponse  = new CheckInventoryResponse();
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "supplier": "foo",
  "supplierName": "ads",
  "supplierLocation": "123",
  "site": "goo",
  "product": [
    {
      "lineItem": 1,
      "manufacturer": "TEST",
      "partNumber": "123",
    },
    {
      "lineItem": 2,
      "manufacturer": "TEST 2",
      "partNumber": "3456",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to populate the POJO with the regular values, but how do I make another `ArrayList` using the `product` part?

I need to do some database checking with the `JSON` but I can't figure out how to save the `ArrayList`.

**heckInventoryResponse**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CheckInventoryResponse implements Serializable {

    private String site;
    private String supplier;
    private String supplierLocation;
    private String supplierName;

    private String lineItem;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String partNumber;

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }
    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }
    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }
    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }
    public String getSupplierLocation() {
        return supplierLocation;
    }
    public void setSupplierLocation(String supplierLocation) {
        this.supplierLocation = supplierLocation;
    }
    public String getSupplierName() {
        return supplierName;
    }
    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    public String getLineItem() {
        return lineItem;
    }
    public void setLineItem(String lineItem) {
        this.lineItem = lineItem;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }
    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }
}
```

This is my POJO class. It can be populated whenever my endpoint is being called, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the product part.

Comment: add CheckInventoryRequest class

Comment: @Prog_G I have the class already with those 3 values and their getters/setters.

Comment: can you share your POJO class?

Comment: @backdoor updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class for Products which will have the details about the product. Try the below classes:

```
class CheckInventoryRequest implements Serializable{
    private String supplier;
    private String supplierName;
    private String supplierLocation;
    private String site;
    private List<Product> product;

    public CheckInventoryRequest() {
    }

    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public String getSupplierName() {
        return supplierName;
    }

    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    public String getSupplierLocation() {
        return supplierLocation;
    }

    public void setSupplierLocation(String supplierLocation) {
        this.supplierLocation = supplierLocation;
    }

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}

class Product implements Serializable{
    private Integer lineItem;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String partNumber;

    public Product() {
    }


    public Integer getLineItem() {
        return lineItem;
    }

    public void setLineItem(Integer lineItem) {
        this.lineItem = lineItem;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }

}
```

Also, the json string is not valid it has extra `,`. Valid json is

```
{
    "supplier": "foo",
    "supplierName": "ads",
    "supplierLocation": "123",
    "site": "goo",
    "product": [
        {
            "lineItem": 1,
            "manufacturer": "TEST",
            "partNumber": "123"
        },
        {
            "lineItem": 2,
            "manufacturer": "TEST 2",
            "partNumber": "3456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the Product as a separate class then make an item in this class as

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

with getter and setter